# How to propagate uncertainty into the prediction of a neural network?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

I have inputs `x_1, ..., x_n` that have known 1-sigma uncertainties `e_1, ..., e_n`. I am using them to predict outputs `y_1, ..., y_m` on a trained neural network. How can I obtain 1-sigma uncertainties on my predictions?

My idea is to randomly perturb each input `x_i` with normal noise having mean 0 and standard deviation `e_i` a large number of times (say, 10000), and then take the median and standard deviation of each prediction `y_i`. Does this work?

I fear that this only takes into account the "random" error (from the measurements) and not the "systematic" error (from the network), i.e., each prediction inherently has some error to it that is not being considered in this approach. How can I properly obtain 1-sigma error bars on my predictions?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't a programming question per se, but rather a machine learning theory question

Answer (score 0):

You can get a general analysis of what "jittering" (generation of random samples) brings to the neural network optimization here http://wojciechczarnecki.com/pdfs/preprint-ml-with-unc.pdf
In short - jittering is just a regularization on network's weights.

For errors bars as such you should refer to works of Will Penny
http://www.fil.ion.ucl.ac.uk/~wpenny/publications/error_bars.ps
http://www.fil.ion.ucl.ac.uk/~wpenny/publications/nnerrors.ps

Answer (score 0):

u r right. That method only takes the data uncertainty into account (assuming u don't fit the neural net while applying the noise). As a side note, alternatively when fitting the data using a neural net u may also apply mixture density networks (see one of the many tutorials).

More importantly, in order to account for model uncertainty u should apply bayesian neural nets. U could could start e.g. with Monte-Carlo dropout. Also very interesting should be this work on performing sampling-free inference when using Monte-Carlo dropout

https://arxiv.org/abs/1908.00598

This work explicitly uses error propagation through neural networks and should be very interesting for u!

Best